# how to get many2one filter value?

Tags: python, odoo

i have following code that is **calender.event** inherited class . there i will create events by **number** sequence . and i have other field like other fields **'inspection_name'** etc

```
    from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api
import logging

class feedback_form(osv.Model):
    _name = 'feedback.form'
    _rec_name = 'inspec_type'
    _columns={
        'folionum' : fields.many2one('calendar.event','Maintainace ID',),
        'folio_number' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio number',),
        'inspec_type' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type',domain="[('inspec_type' , '=' , folio_number)]"),

        'frequency' : fields.char('Frequency'),
        'shutdown' : fields.char('Shout Down'),
        'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Result',domain="[('inspec_type', '=', inspec_type)]"),
    }

    def onchange_folio(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum, context=None):
        dids = []
        for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
            dids = [x.id for x in record.folio_num]
        return {'domain':{'folio_number':[('id','in',dids)]}}

    '''def onchange_insp(self, cr, uid, ids, folio_number, context=None):
        dids = []
        for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folio_number, context=context):
            dids = [x.id for x in record.inspection_name]
        return {'domain':{'inspec_type':[('id','in',dids)]}}'''

    def onchange_measure(self, cr, uid, ids, inspec_type, context=None):
        dids = []
        for record in self.pool.get('asset1.inspection').browse(cr, uid, inspec_type, context=context):
            dids = [x.id for x in record.msr_insp]
        return {'domain':{'insp_msr1':[('id','in',dids)]}}
```

**calendar.event**

from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api

class calendar_event(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = "calendar.event"
_rec_name = 'number'

_columns = {
        'number' : fields.char('Meeting ID',readonly=1),
        #'place' : fields.many2one('stock.location','Substation Location',),

        'place' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Substation Location',),
        #'location' : fields.selection(STATUS_SELECTION,'Location',  default='Board A'),
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg','Asset Catg Selection',),
            'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name','Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2many('agile.portfolio1','agile_portfolio1_rel','super_id','agile_portfolio1_id','Asset Model Code',),
        'folio_num' : fields.many2many('asset.asset','asset_asset_rel','super_id','asset_asset_id','Folio Num',),
        #'inspection_name' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type', ),
        'inspection_name' : fields.many2many('asset1.inspection','asset1_inspection_rel','super_id','asset1_inspection_id','Inspection Type'),
        #'folio_num' : fields.related('folio_num','folio_num',string='Folio Num',relation='asset.asset', type='many2one')    
        }


_defaults = {
            'number' : lambda self,cr,uid,context={}:self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr,uid,'calendar.event'),
            }
```

Comment: whatever i am trying with def function its getting error like AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'

Answer (score 0):

## First

I guess it pretty simple typo mistake that you have done, the statement:

`mesure_fil = self.pool.get('calender.event')`

should be :

`mesure_fil = self.pool.get('calendar.event')`

You have typo on model name.

## Second

You need to chnage the cod eof your on_chnage method here to make it work  correctly :

```
def onchange_folio(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum, context=None):
    dids = []
    for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
            dids = [x.id for x in record.inspection_name]
    return {'domain':{'inspec_type':[('id','in',dids)]}}
```

and in your form view please make sure that your code is called like this

```
<field name="folionum" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" on_change="onchange_folio(folionum)"/>
```

This will work correctly.

Bests

Comment: i have done this but again its not filtering . is that function correct ?... please get me solution i need this at any condition

Comment: On on chnage of field you can't change the domain or add domain.

Comment: @Shridhar Ivani: Its complex to achieve this, you need to create one extra field.function and put the on change code in functional field. that field will hold value for you and then make your domain in view based on that field. and add that function field in view with invisible True. Complex but work as functional field is store false so no load on DB.

Comment: please can you drop code so that i can understand more about it

Comment: Sure, I can but their is design issue with your code. You trying to add domain on field inspec_type which is in relationship with asset1.inspection, while your code is searching calendar. event as per your code, do you really want that ?!?

Comment: just i want only those inspec_type which are assigned to 'number' field . that inspec_type is many2one from asset1.inspection. or even i am okay if we get only calendar.event inspec_type in 'feedback.form'. if you have any doubt please drop your skype id to this mail id shridharivani@gmail.com

Comment: bro i have done loot of stuffs so now i am struck at some point if you help me for this . it would be great . please

Comment: def _get_folio(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, context=None): what is this 'field_name' . is this folio_num or 'number' from calendar.event

Comment: Just default parameters That you have to have to fields. Function function, you can't remove it, just leave it alone as it's required by framework, check Def func here ; https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type/#functional-fields and you nees args too which I have missed

Comment: Sorry,  but You need to wait utill tomorrow as I m away form computer and I can't test code.  I can give working code tomorrow.

Comment: yeah i will be bro . is it possible right if you want i will drop you dependencies code please . i need your help

Comment: @ShridharIvani : added right comment in original answer.

Comment: when i select folio num i only get false,false .. in many2one list . after selection any one false evn not able get any inspection name there

Comment: its working fine bro thanks a looot its very great work

Comment: hey bro i have this requirement. but here i was trying with your code its giving key_error:4 . Intially filter was done with "folionum". Please here i am missing something . i want to filter by 'calendar.event' form please please help me @firebug bro

Comment: what ever i am commented function is there that is somethin i am looking at